# How can I update core to 8.9.10?

Tags: 8, composer

I'm trying to apply the security update for core by updating it to [8.9.10](https://www.drupal.org/sa-core-2020-013) with the following command:

```
composer update drupal/core
```

But this only brings back the following notice:

> Nothing to install or update

What am I doing wrong? How can I update core to 8.9.10?

Comment: Can you maybe add your composer.json to your question? Is it maybe `drupal/core-recommended`? Did you also try `composer update drupal/core drupal/core-dev --with-dependencies`?

Comment: Also try [`composer update drupal/core 'drupal/core-*' --with-all-dependencies`](https://www.drupal.org/docs/updating-drupal/updating-drupal-core-via-composer#s-update-drupal-core-code).

Comment: `composer update drupal/core drupal/core-dev --with-dependencies`did the trick... thank you very much. I did not update the composer.json to require `drupal/core-recommended`, it still required `drupal/core` - will need to change that

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to @leymannx

```
composer update drupal/core drupal/core-dev --with-dependencies
```

did it

Comment: Correct, and if you ever have trouble finding out what blocks an update for core, then you can run `composer prohibits drupal/core:8.9.10` in this particular case.